# MS Azure doesn't install virtualenv for Django project. error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, azure

I have a problem with deploy my Django project to MS Azure.I working on Linux env. I made files runtime.txt, requirements.txt and push it to Azure, but I have trouble when the service tried to install mysqlclient. Azure tried install this lib from source code, not wheel file. After this situation I have added .whl file to my project in folder 'wheelhouse' and changed requirement.txt, next I pushed it and took the same error: **error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat**. Here log file from Azure, structure my project, requirements.txt

|project/

|--app/

|--wheelhouse/

|----mysqlclient-1.3.10-cp35.whl

---

reuirements.txt

--find-links wheelhouse

mysqlclient==1.3.10

Django==1.10.4

---

Log from azure

> Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd" Handling python
>   deployment. Detected requirements.txt.  You can skip Python specific
>   steps with a .skipPythonDeployment file. Detecting Python runtime from
>   runtime.txt Detected python-3.4 Found compatible virtual environment.
>   Pip install requirements. Downloading/unpacking mysqlclient==1.3.10
>   (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))   Running setup.py
>   (path:D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\mysqlclient\setup.py) egg_info
>   for package mysqlclient
>
> ```
> warning: no files found matching 'GPL-2.0' Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Django==1.10.4 in
> ```
>
> d:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt
>   (line 3)) Installing collected packages: mysqlclient   Running
>   setup.py install for mysqlclient
>       building '_mysql' extension
>       error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
>       Complete output from command D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\mysqlclient\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record
>   D:\local\Temp\pip-8m_f_kxa-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\include\site\python3.4:
>       running install
>
> running build
>
> running build_py
>
> creating build
>
> creating build\lib.win32-3.4
>
> copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4
>
> creating build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb
>
> copying MySQLdb__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb
>
> copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb
>
> copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb
>
> copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb
>
> copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb
>
> copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb
>
> copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb
>
> creating build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
>
> copying MySQLdb\constants__init__.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
>
> copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
>
> copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
>
> copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
>
> copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
>
> copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
>
> copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb\constants
>
> running build_ext
>
> building '_mysql' extension
>
> error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
>
> ---------------------------------------- Cleaning up... Command D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\mysqlclient\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record
>   D:\local\Temp\pip-8m_f_kxa-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\include\site\python3.4 failed with error code
>   1 in D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\mysqlclient Storing debug log for
>   failure in D:\home\pip\pip.log An error has occurred during web site
>   deployment. \r\nD:\Program Files
>   (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\61.60316.2745\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd
>   "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by an old pip on WebApp by default. You have two solutions:

- Prefered: Do not use default Python on WebApps (I guess it's a WebApp?), use a Python extension. They are up to date with latest pip and you can use Python 3.6.1:

  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/08/04/upgrading-python-on-azure-app-service/
- Avoid this solution unless you have a specific reason to do so: Create a virtualenv with the default Python and update pip first (from a Kudu console it's simple "pip install -U pip"